# I want to mint and airdrop NFTs to my users without them paying gas. Is there a tool that does this?

Tags: nft, airdrop

I'm interested in minting and airdropping NFTs to my users without them having to pay gas fees.If you know of any tools or services that can help accomplish this, I would greatly appreciate your suggestions- elchuo160

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using [Metaplex's](https://docs.metaplex.com/guides/airdrops#token-airdrop) [Gumdrop](https://gumdrop.metaplex.com/) program.

- First, the receivers need to be whitelisted by doing something like the following:

```
[{"handle":"name1@example.com","amount":1500000000},{"handle":"name2@example.com","amount":1500000000}]
```

- The second step would be that the receivers will need to go to the airdrop URL and, verify the ownership of the handle, then claim it.

**Another way** is to use `cm_mintNFTIdempotent` method of the Crossmint NFT Mint API Add-on from [QuickNode Marketplace](https://docs.metaplex.com/guides/airdrops#token-airdrop).

One of the major benefits of using the Crossmint Add-on via the QuickNode Marketplace is that you can mint, airdrop nfts, etc + you can also do all the Solana native JSON-RPC operations, all with one single QuickNode endpoint.

Here's a JavaScript example:

```
const axios = require("axios");
(() => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };
  const data = {
    jsonrpc: "2.0",
    id: 1,
    method: "cm_mintNFTIdempotent",
    params: ["FILL_ME_ARG_1", "FILL_ME_ARG_2", "FILL_ME_ARG_3", "FILL_ME_ARG_4"],
  };
  axios
    .post(
      "https://FILL_YOUR_ENDPOINT_HERE.com",
      data,
      config
    )
    .then(function (response) {
      // handle success
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // handle error
      console.log(err);
    });
})();
```

Check out the documentation for more info --> https://marketplace.quicknode.com/add-on/nft-mint-api-mainnet/

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing is the Octane protocol https://github.com/solana-labs/octane, which is designed for that exact usecase. This way, users can claim without draining your wallet.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an NFT minter where you use your keypair to mint the NFT but set the ownership / transfer the ownership to the user interacting with it. Possible with Solana Pay as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/mordonez-me/solana-poap to:

- create a collection
- create a candy machine
- airdrop users with a wallet list

If you need help using it I can help you, just let me know on twitter.